# Why is SQLite3 automatically encrypting a database I create?

Tags: database, sqlite

I am trying to get a thorough understanding of sqlite3 so that I can run some basic queries through DB Browser for SQLite (http://sqlitebrowser.org/).

To do so, I've imported NYC Taxi data for 1 month, and tried (for many hours) to import this data on sqlite3.

```
.mode csv <Table_Name>
.import <path/to/file/data.csv> <Table_Name>
```

Once that finishes, I issue the following SQL statement:

```
.out <path/to/file/data.db>
select * from <table_name>;
```

Then, when I try to use DB Browser for SQLite to verify that the database has been populated with data, I get a prompt:

> SQLCipher Encryption
>
> Please enter the key used to encrypt the database

Why is it getting auto-encrypted?  Is there another way to get my csv file into a database?

Comment: What OS? Where did you install SQLite from?

Comment: MacOS, Anaconda Python distribution.  I believe SQLite comes standard with MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

The message means that the file is not recognized as a database file. This can happen if the file *is* encrypted.

But in this case, the output generated by `.output` is the same as what would be printed on the screen. This is not a database file at all.

To get a copy of the entire database file, use `.backup`.

To get a copy of a single table, use `.dump tablename`, then execute those SQL statements in a new database:

```
sqlite3 data.db < file_generated_by_dump
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to answer the question of why the database is becoming encrypted.

Comment: @alex Because the database is *not* becoming encrypted.